# How could I get more data about pending transaction?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, txpool

How would I be able to get more data about a pending transaction in the mempool? I am interested in getting data about,

1. Value of transaction
2. Gas used
3. Who the transaction is from and where it is going

I have a nodejs server which I have used to subscribe to the mempool, but this alone only returns the transaction hash. I have tried the `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` and `web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)`.

```
 var subscription = web3.eth
 .subscribe("pendingTransactions", function (error, result) {
 if (!error) console.log(result);
 })
 .on("data", function (transaction) {
 console.log(transaction);
 });
```

Is it even possible to get more details of a pending transaction? I would like to scan for incoming transactions for my arb bot.

Comment: `getTransaction()` should give you the desired info, what are you getting when you try it?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but DeFi arbitrage is already being done by very sophisticated firms/developers. The question you are asking is very simple compared to the many other challenges you will have to face to get an edge against the other arbitrageur. However, if you do this just for fun and have no expectation of profit, why not!

Comment: @Undead8, I know, it's just a project that motivates me to learn more.

Comment: @pwagner, it simply just returns null (as it's pending)

Comment: web3.py has what you're looking for, one method call to return pending transactions with all their data  https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.geth.html?highlight=txpool#web3.geth.txpool.TxPool.content